# How can I verify section -> segment mapping for ELFs on linux?

Tags: linux, gdb, elf

I'm looking at at ELF on linux and I have `readelf --segments ./myELF` which shows:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R   0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000400238 0x0000000000400238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000ad8 0x000ad8 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x000e00 0x0000000000600e00 0x0000000000600e00 0x000250 0x000260 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x000e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0000000000600e10 0x0001e0 0x0001e0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000400254 0x0000000000400254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000940 0x0000000000400940 0x0000000000400940 0x00004c 0x00004c R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x000e00 0x0000000000600e00 0x0000000000600e00 0x000200 0x000200 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got
```

I am trying to confirm whether or not the segments shown here correspond directly with the segment numbers shown in the section-segment mapping below such that segment 03 which contains `.init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss`  corresponds with the *fourth* segment down in the top table which is of type `LOAD` and will thus *definitely* RW at runtime? What is another way to learn about the segment/section mapping at runtime? I know for example that I can use `vmmap` in `gdb-gef` at runtime to view where things are located in the process' virtual memory, but it seems that output shows a different set of memory spaces than the specific concept of "segments" or "sections".

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing in `gdb` with the `vmmap` command is the region allocations. To determine which region a section has been loaded in you can use the `maintenance info sections` command.

For example:

```
gef➤  vmmap 
[ Legend:  Code | Heap | Stack ]
Start              End                Offset             Perm Path
0x00000000400000 0x00000000401000 0x00000000000000 r-x /home/...
0x00000000600000 0x00000000601000 0x00000000000000 r-- /home/...
0x00000000601000 0x00000000602000 0x00000000001000 rw- /home/...
```

The writable region starts at 0x00000000601000.

```
gef➤  maintenance info sections
Exec file: `/home/...', file type elf64-x86-64.
...
 [23]     0x00601040->0x00601044 at 0x00001040: .data ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS
 [24]     0x00601044->0x00601048 at 0x00001044: .bss ALLOC
...
```

Only the `.data` and `.bss` sections are within the writable region at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. So one followup here - my ELF has a situation where the .got shows this when I run `maintenance info sections`: `[21] 0x00600ff8->0x00601000 at 0x00000ff8: .got ALLOC LOAD DATA HAS_CONTENTS`, however, in the `vm` readout, the permission is only `r--`. So now I'm wondering why the `maint info sections` listing doesn't also show the `READONLY` tag? I would expect that tag would be applied since according to `vm` that memory is in fact only readonly, but it's not. See reference example: `0x00400520->0x00400722 at 0x00000520: .text ALLOC LOAD READONLY CODE HAS_CONTENTS`

Comment: I'm not sure... just guessing, the GOT is fixed up by the loader so it does need to be writable at least at some point while the process is being started.